# SoLoud Audio not playing

Tags: c++, audio

I'm looking for some help to get the audio library SoLoud to work I've written out the quickstart from the documentation page here https://sol.gfxile.net/soloud/quickstart.html, opting for the static library route, but it doesn't seem to play no matter what I've tried many different wav files, I've stepped through and the file seems to be loading correctly and no failures in any of the methods seem to be occurring. everything seems to be included and linking correctly as I've got no errors of any kind anywhere. just no sound. I'm thinking maybe I've set it up incorrectly somehow but I can't find anything wrong. Anyway, here's the source any help would be appreciated.

````
#include "soloud.h"
#include "soloud_wav.h"



int main()
{
    SoLoud::Soloud gSoloud; // SoLoud engine
    SoLoud::Wav gWave;      // One wave file

    gSoloud.init(); // Initialize SoLoud

    int x = gWave.load("A.wav"); // Load a wave
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    gSoloud.play(gWave); // Play the wave



    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Silly me forgetting my thread logic the process terminates when the program ends and its child threads that are playing the audio die as per the OS. Which I forgot. So the simple solution is a loop and there you have it audio.